# AngularJS translate object attribute

Tags: angularjs, internationalization

In my angular directive, I have an object with 2 attributes : object.title_en (the title in english) and object.title_fr (the title in french). How to display and keep displaying the correct title according to the current language that I get by $translate.use() ?

**EDIT**

Here is my HTML template:

`<div layout="column">
    <div>
        {{object.title_fr | limitTo: 50}}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{object.description_fr | limitTo: 150}}
    </div>
</div>`

And here is my JSON object that I get :

`{
        "title_en" : "Title in english",
        "title_fr" : "Title in french",
        "description_en" : "Description in english",
        "description_fr" : "Description in french"
}`

And I would like to be able to translate it into english according to the current language $translate.use().

Comment: Hi Annelhote, you may want to try posting a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of your code.  This helps people see exactly what you're trying to do and shows some effort on your part to accomplish the goal.  People are more likely to help when they can see some effort on the asker's part.

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You need to use a JSON object for each language. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Change your JSON object to two separate objects. Then you specify which one to use for each language.

Here is an example:

```
myModule.config(['$translateProvider', function($translateProvider) {
    var language_fr={
        "title" : "Title in french",
        "description" : "Description in french"
    };

    var language_en= {
        "title" : "Title in english",
        "description" : "Description in english",
    };

    $translateProvider
        .translations('en', language_en)
        .translations('fr', language_fr)
        .preferredLanguage('en')
        .fallbackLanguage('en')
        .useSanitizeValueStrategy('escape')
    ;
}]);
```

Then you can use it in your HTML like this:

    `<div layout="column">
        <div translate>title</div>
        <div translate>description</div>
    </div>`